# TinyMCE windowManager open HTML form with translation

Tags: localization, internationalization, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am migrating a TinyMCE 3.x plugin to 4.x

The plugin uses a number of dialogs defined by individual HTML files.  These files have internationalized strings inside, e.g.,

```
<select id="reading" name="reading">
  <option value="corr">{#wce.correction}</option>
  <option value="comm">{#wce.commentary}</option>
  <option value="alt">{#wce.alternative}</option>
</select>
```

In TinyMCE 3.x it seems the popup plugin ran this content through tinymce's translate facility, but using 4.x, calling:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open
```

the strings don't get translated.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so looking at the 3.x tinymce_popup code, I have grabbed the appropriate lines and am now doing this in my dialog html files:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   translate();
 });
 function translate() {
   var c=document.body.innerHTML;
   var d=document.title;
   var a;
   if(top.tinymce.isIE){c=c.replace(/ (value|title|alt)=([^"][^\s>]+)/gi,' $1="$2"')}
   a=c.replace(/\{\#([^\}]+)\}/g, function(a, b) {
     var c=top.tinymce.translate(b); 
     return (c != b) ? c : '{#' + b + '}';
   });
   if(a!=c){document.body.innerHTML=a}
   a=d.replace(/\{\#([^\}]+)\}/g, function(a, b) {
     var c=top.tinymce.translate(b);
     return (c != b) ? c : '{#' + b + '}';
   });
   if(a!=d){document.title=d=a}
 }
```

I also had to edit my plugin locale files to remove the plugin name from the registration of the strings. e.g., from:

```
tinyMCE.addI18n('en.wce',{
  'key' : 'value',
  ...
```

to

```
tinymce.addI18n('en',{
  'key' : 'value',
  ...
```

and all my

```
 {#wce.tokens}
```

to simply

```
 {#tokens}
```

in my HTML.

This gets me mostly working now.  Hope it's helpful to others.

Comment: The body of this 'translate' method seems overly complicated, as much of this code is in the Editor.translate method, but for some reason editor.translate doesn't have my plugin language pack available, but tinymce.translate does have my plugin language pack available.  Unfortunately, tinymce.translate doesn't include the code to do the token replacement.  So, stands as-is until we can get an official answer how to do this easily with TinyMCE 4.x.